# Genefiltering in R

Tags: r

I am trying to look for genes expressed differently in two different stages. I am using a dataset within R ("ALL") and am looking for genes expressed differently in "B2" and "B3". I am trying to use `genefilter()` to program a couple of tests into it separately for each gene, and am running into a couple of errors I am not sure how to correct. Here is the code I have so far:

```
library("genefilter")
library(ALL)
data(ALL)
Bcells <- c("B2","B3")
stages <- ALL$BT[Bcells]
patientB<- factor(ALL$BT[Bcells])
f1<-function(x) (wilcox.test(x~patientB,exact=F)$p.value<0.001)
f2<-function(x) (t.test(x~patientB)$p.value<0.001)
yes1 <- genefilter(exprs(ALL), filterfun(f1))
yes2 <- genefilter(exprs(ALL), filterfun(f2))
yes <- yes1 & yes2
all<- ALL[yes,]
all
```

The error I am getting is that the variable lengths differ for "patientB" that I have defined --

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = x ~ patientB) : variable lengths differ (found for 'patientB')

and this is not running the `genefilter()` command.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not subsetting from the expression matrix or the vector of patients correctly. The lines you want to use to select just the patients B2 and B3 are:

```
ALL_filtered <- ALL[, ALL$BT %in% Bcells]
patientB<- factor(ALL$BT[ALL$BT %in% Bcells])
```

Then you'll be able to do:

```
f1<-function(x) (wilcox.test(x~patientB,exact=F)$p.value<0.001)
f2<-function(x) (t.test(x~patientB)$p.value<0.001)
yes1 <- genefilter(exprs(ALL_filtered), filterfun(f1))
yes2 <- genefilter(exprs(ALL_filtered), filterfun(f2))
yes <- yes1 & yes2
all<- ALL[yes,]
all
```

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense.